# could not find an overload for '+' that accepts the supplied arguments

Tags: swift

So I am trying to convert a game I was making in Objective-C to Swift.

I am trying to get this to work, but it keeps giving me an error.

```
    var actualX = (Double(arc4random() ) % Double(rangeX) ) + Double(minX);
```

I have also tried:

```
    var actualX = (arc4random() % rangeX) + minX;
```

I have looked at the other posts on Stack Overflow of similar problems, but none of them have helped or solved my problem...

Comment: What is rangeX and minX?

Comment: If you put `Double(...)` around the entire first expression does that work? Like `Double(Double(arc4random()) % Double(rangeX))`

Comment: What's the actual error? What are the definitions of the variables used in the expression? Help us out here.

Comment: The actual error is the title of the post. rangeX and minX are variables that are initialized to be integers. The `Double(...)` didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`arc4random()` returns a `UInt32`, any argument to your `%` operator has to be a compatible type.

Co-erce your variables to a `UInt32`. You don't mention what type they are, but I am assuming they are some form of integer. You can obviously coerce to another type later.

```
var actualX = (arc4random() % UInt32(rangeX)) + UInt32(minX)
```

This is a result of the strong typing in swift.

Comment: Thank you!!! :D Still new to programming so I had no idea that arc4random returned that type of value.

Comment: If you hold down the command key, and click on `arc4random()` in your code, the header files will open, which show the return value. Double click to open in a new window.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me:

```
import Cocoa

let minX = 3.2
let rangeX = 42.0 

let actualX = (Double(arc4random()) % rangeX) + minX
```

After execution actualX will be a Double because of type inference of Swift.

@otherRepliants: Of course arc4random() returns an UInt32, but why not cast it to Double. Works fine.